# Как сделать запрос на получение файла?

Tags: javascript

На нужной мне странице есть такая ссылка, при нажатии на нее выдается запрос на сохранение файла. Можно ли как-то из java-кода получить этот файл?

Ссылка:

```
<a id="ctl00_BXContent_lbCSV"     href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BXContent$lbCSV','')">CSV (разделители - точка с запятой)</a>
```

Код JavaScript:

```
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @b1ack_ange1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Традиционный тэг java в вопросе по javascript /=

Comment: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/users/22959/smackmychi">@smackmychi</a>, мое приложение на JSF, и из бина надо получить файл.

Answer (score 1):

Как выглядит форма?

В простом случае, из приведённого кода следует, что отправляется форма, в которой добавляются поля `__EVENTTARGET = 'ctl00$BXContent$lbCSV'` и `__EVENTARGUMENT = ''`, а в ответ отдаётся искомый файл с заголовком типа `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"`.

Чтобы обрабатывать этот файл в JS, наверное, можно вместо отправки формы, запросить ajax'ом тот же URL, и передать те же данные.

Comment: @srgiks, вот адрес http://nprts.ru/ru/otc_market/board/INFO/archive/rtsboardmarketresults.aspx , нажать кнопку "Показать" и отобразиться нужная мне страница.

Comment: Нужно отправить не GET, а POST запрос на чистый адрес `http://nprts.ru/ru/otc_market/board/INFO/archive/rtsboardmarketresults.aspx`, где в теле запроса будут присутствовать две упомянутые `__EVENT*`, а ещё, может, и `__VIEWSTATE` (см. исходный код страницы - ищите тег `<form`).

Посмотрите FireBug'ом или другим браузерным инструментом, какой запрос фактически отправляется, когда вы нажимаете «Показать». [Вот, какие данные у меня уходят](http://pastebin.com/50G9RQ7a).

Comment: Пробовал вот тут https://www.hurl.it/ отравлять запросы, но, кроме 500 ошибки, ничего в ответ не получал, отправлял все параметры, присутствовавшие в onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятна задача, но похоже что вам могло бы подойти File API. У Mail.ru неплохое хранилище (репозиторий?) есть http://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/ и на хабре статья была http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/201010/ Но я, правда, не уверн, это ли вам надо.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, но это, к сожалению, не то, что мне нужно. Я хотел бы получать данный файл CSV для последующего его разбора. Но так как этот файл недоступен по прямой ссылке, я не знаю, как можно было бы к нему еще обратиться.